Calculate maximum degree of a tree given $x$ nodes and every node in tree has at max $y$ children.
Given a tree and the following data:

The tree consists out of $x$ nodes
Every node in the tree can have at maximum $y$ children.

How can I calculate the degree of a tree? So the maximum number of children starting at the leaf.
